# spark-shell cannot find the class to be extended

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Why cannot I load the file with the following code in spark-shell

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             

import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Aggregator                                                                                                                                                                                                                              


case class Data(i: Int)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         

val customSummer =  new Aggregator[Data, Int, Int] {                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
  def zero: Int = 0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
  def reduce(b: Int, a: Data): Int = b + a.i                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  def merge(b1: Int, b2: Int): Int = b1 + b2                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  def finish(r: Int): Int = r                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
}.toColumn()
```

The error:

```
<console>:47: error: object creation impossible, since:
it has 2 unimplemented members.
/** As seen from <$anon: org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Aggregator[Data,Int,Int]>, the missing signatures are as follows.
 *  For convenience, these are usable as stub implementations.
 */
  def bufferEncoder: org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder[Int] = ???
  def outputEncoder: org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder[Int] = ???

       val customSummer =  new Aggregator[Data, Int, Int] {
```

**Update**: @user8371915's solution works. But the following script cannot be loaded with a different error. I used `:load script.sc` in the spark-shell.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Aggregator
class MyClass extends Aggregator
```

Error:

```
loading ./script.sc...
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Aggregator
<console>:11: error: not found: type Aggregator
       class MyClass extends Aggregator
```

**Update**(2017-12-03): it doesn't seem to work within Zeppelin, either.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per error message you didn't implement `bufferEncoder` and `outputEncoder`. Please check [API docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/#org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Aggregator) for the list of `abstract` methods that have to be implemented.

These two should suffice:

```
def bufferEncoder: Encoder[Int] = Encoders.scalaInt
def outputEncoder: Encoder[Int] = Encoders.scalaInt
```